# Create list of strings that repeats first element and adds _1 _2 up to _n in Google Earth Engine's java editor

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

In order to rename the bands of a stacked image, I need a list of the stack's bands, and a list of what I want them to be named. I have made the latter but not the former. It needs to work with stacks containing various numbers of images.

What I need - a list that is HH, HH_1, HH_2 etc up to HH_n-1 of n length.

I've created a list of n length, by the following:

```
var HHlist = ee.List.repeat('HH', n)
```

but that just gives HH x the desired number.

I've also made a list of 1 to n, which I thought could somehow be combined.

```
var sequence = ee.List.sequence(1, n);
```

Comment: You can simply do a for loop from 0 to n and inside you push a new element to the list with your string + _ + your cycle counter

Comment: Thank you. For loops are 'discouraged' in GEE (see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_js_03). I suspect it can be done with the map function but I'm not sure how.

Comment: oh just took a peek at it, i guess you could generate your sequence list like you said and then map it like sequence.map(i => "HH_"+i)